# Fragment does not call lifecycle methods

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've a fragment A. I `add()` it with tag like this:

```
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(special_tag);
```

Then I simply `add()` fragment B on top of fragment A. After that, I decide to remove fragment B and go back to fragment A using:

```
activity.fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate(special_tag, 0)
```

When I reach the fragment A, it seems that fragment doesn't re-run it's lifecycle methods: onAttach(), onResume(), onCreate() ect.

Can someone explain this behavior and maybe suggest an alternative?

(I need to "refresh" the data when I come back to fragment A second time)

1. What is causing this result?
2. Is there a clean solution/work-around?

**Update**

Fragment B is `GuidedStepFragment` and does not have a `.replace()` function. I found that it has `finishGuidedStepFragments()`, but it behaves the same (it does not call fragment life cycle functions)

Situation (again):

Fragment A (**Simple** fragment) -> .add(Fragment B) (GuidedStepFragment) -> `popBackStackImmediate()` or `finishGuidedStepFragments()`

I add Fragment B like this:

```
GuidedStepFragment.add(activity.fragmentManager, fragmentB.createInstance())
```

Comment: Do you call `add()` in fragment A? If so, please add the code you use for that fragment transaction.

Comment: Also, is Fragment A a `GuidedStepFragment`?

Comment: @Jon Updated! Fragment A is simple fragment.

Comment: Ok now that makes sense. Do you need to use `GuidedStepFragment` for your application? It was built with the purpose of overlaying your existing ui. If you cannot see any of Fragment A when you add Fragment B, then I don't see the value of a `GuidedStepFragment` versus a normal fragment.

Comment: Yes, I must use it. Fragment A holds recyclerview items. When I add Fragment B (GuidedStepFragment) it guides user to "add" new item to recyclerview. When User finishes fragment B, I re-direct user back to fragment A, but I want to update DATA, which I was planning to do in some of life-cycle methods. Is there a cleaner alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `fragmentTransaction.add(Fragment)` doesn't remove Fragment A. What is actually happening is that Fragment A is **still running** behind Fragment B. Since Fragment A never stopped running, it's lifecycle has no need to retrigger.

Consider using `fragmentTransaction.replace(Fragment)` and replace the fragment in the container (fragment A) with fragment B. If you pop that transaction from the back stack, then Fragment A will reattach and follow your expected lifecycle.

**Update**

Since you seem to be using `GuidedStepFragment`s from the leanback library, this is a little tricky. `GuidedStepFragment` actually performs `replace(...)` under the hood, but you're adding fragment B to a different container so the original behavior I mentioned doesn't apply.

I'm not super familiar with leanback (since it's usually only used for android tv), but I do know that you can at least do the following. If you keep track of your backstack size, when all of the `GuidedStepFragment`s have been popped, you will have returned to your original fragment. For example, let's assume your backstack starts at zero:

```
activity.fragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBackStackChanged() {
                if (activity.fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() == 0){
                    // handle your updates
                }
            }
        });

 // the next line of code will add an entry to the backstack
 GuidedStepFragment.add(activity.fragmentManager, fragmentB.createInstance());
// eventually when back is pressed and the guided fragment is removed, the backstack listener should trigger
```

Comment: What if I need to have an option to go back with back-button when I'm in fragment B (to fragment A)? If I use .replace, then this will not be possible.

Comment: It is possible, it works exactly like you do it now. You have to check for android.R.id.home in fragment.onOptionSelected().

Comment: if you add the `replace(...)` to the backstack, then when you pop that transaction, a reverse replace will occur. Think of the backstack as "undo the latest transaction". As @ElDuderino said, it's the exactly the same behavior you already have.

Comment: @JoshuaMad Updated the answer